# django signals, the right way

Tags: django

okay, i have a generic question .. I want to have my models.py very clean ... no other stuff other than declaring the models.

lets say i have this as models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model:
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    #other stuff
```

and this is my signals.py

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

how do i go about telling my application that this is my signals file? .. do i have to declare them in my models.py?

//mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - I saw one way of doing it I liked. Create receivers.py or signals.py in the same app, and put your signal receiving methods and then just import all of them and connect to signals in models.py.

Or even (f.e. if you like to use decorators for defining connected signals, which I always use) - import whole receivers.py at the end of models.py: `from app.receivers import *`

Only thing I don't like in this solution is that it sometimes ends with circular dependencies you must care about.

Comment: This solution is pretty much the only way to do it, but the circular dependencies are a killer, especially when you're using apps like Haystack that employ autodiscover (pure evil).  If you must do it, use explicit imports versus `import *`.

@mouse, I applaud your desire for clean code, but this is a case where it's better to put signals at the end of models.py -- I have the same penchant for clean code and this one resulted in me pulling my hair out too often later on.

Comment: thanks. clean code helps when it comes to mantaining a software

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the `signals.py` somewhere so that it gets executed and django registers the signals and handlers.

Preferably, include it in `models.py` so that it gets included early enough so that signal handlers are registered before any signal is generated.

Comment: if i do it in models.py .. wouldn't it create a circular dependency?

Comment: @mouse You can either move import signals at the end of `models.py` or import  model from models.py inside signal handler function rather than at global scope.